# Write and display automatically generated html code

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I am generating html code out of a python list.

```
import webbrowser

food_list = [(u'John Doe', 1.73),(u'Jane Doe', 1.73), (u'Jackie O', 1.61)]


def print_html(lista):
    print '<table>'
    for i in food_list:
        print '<tr>'
        print '<td>'+str(i[0]) +'</td>''<td>'+str(i[1])+'</td>'
        print '</tr>'
    print' </table>'

code = print_html(food_list)
print code

h = open('list.html','w')

h.write(code)
h.close()

webbrowser.open_new_tab('list.html')
```

I cannot write "code" to an html file for displaying it.

Error message:

```
    h.write(code)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I would prefer not to hardcode the html code.

It must be so simple that I cannot figure it out.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you print the code and see there is nothing in the code because you are just printing and not returning

Comment: You are trying to write `None` which is what your function returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything so you are trying to write None, do the writing in the function passing the filename and the list:

```
def write_html(lista,f):
    with open(f, "w") as f:
        f.write('<table>')
        for i in lista:
            f.write('<tr>')
            f.write('<td>'+str(i[0]) +'</td>''<td>'+str(i[1])+'</td>')
            f.write( '</tr>')
        f.write('</table>')

write_html(food_list,"list.html")
webbrowser.open_new_tab('list.html')
```

Output:

```
John Doe    1.73
Jane Doe    1.73
Jackie O    1.61
```

You can concatenate and then write but if your goal is to just write it is easier to write as you iterate over the list.

If you run your code you will see the return value at the end:

In [27]: print pri
print       print_html

```
In [27]: print print_html(food_list)
<table>
<tr>
<td>John Doe</td><td>1.73</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jane Doe</td><td>1.73</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jackie O</td><td>1.61</td>
</tr>
 </table>
None # what you are trying to write
```

You could also `from __future__ import print_function` and use print to write to the file:

```
def write_html(lista,f):
    with open(f, "w") as f:
        print('<table>',file=f)
        for i in lista:
            print('<tr>',file=f)
            print('<td>'+str(i[0]) +'</td>''<td>'+str(i[1])+'</td>',file=f)
            print( '</tr>',file=f)
        print(' </table>',file=f)
```

Or use the python2 syntax:

```
def write_html(lista,f):
    with open(f, "w") as f:
        print >>f, '<table>'
        for i in lista:
            print >>f,'<tr>'
            print >>f, '<td>'+str(i[0]) +'</td>''<td>'+str(i[1])+'</td>'
            print >>f, '</tr>'
        print >>f,' </table>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Python's own html package:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html/

```
from html import HTML
h = HTML()
table = h.table()
food_list = [(u'John Doe', 1.73),(u'Jane Doe', 1.73), (u'Jackie O', 1.61)]
for i in food_list:
    row = table.tr
    row.td(str(i[0]))
    row.td(str(i[1]))


h = open('list.html','w')

h.write(str(table))
h.close()
```

Comment: Good yours is a more module oriented

Comment: This is a workaround as opposed to an explanation as to  why the code does not work

Comment: You're right. I would edit my response, but I think he has plenty of feedback by now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this code.

Since you printed the variable nothing was returned .Due to which error appeared

```
import webbrowser

food_list = [(u'John Doe', 1.73),(u'Jane Doe', 1.73), (u'Jackie O', 1.61)]


def print_html(food_list):
    a=""
    a=a+'<table>\n'
    for i in food_list:
        a=a+'<tr>\n'
        a=a+'<td>'+str(i[0]) +'</td>''<td>'+str(i[1])+'</td>\n'
        a=a+'</tr>\n'
    a=a+' </table>\n'
    return a

code = print_html(food_list)
print str(code)

h = open('list.html','w')

h.write(str(code))
h.close()

webbrowser.open_new_tab('list.html')
```

Now run it and see

It showed error in the first place because the code variable belonged to none type